# Column line missing after "E"?

Tags: tables, pdftex, multicol, multirow, article

Column line missing after "E"? Can someone help me solve it? [image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \caption{Title} \label{tab:addlabel}%
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{A} &\multirow{2}{*}{B} & \multirow{2}{*}{C} & \multirow{2}{*}{D} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{E} & \multirow{2}{*}{F} & \multirow{2}{*}{G} & \multirow{2}{*}{H} \\
\cline{5-8}
& &  &  & M & N&O&P          &  &  &  \\
\cline{1-11}    
\end{tabular}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\multicolumn{4}{c|}{E}` instead of `\multicolumn{4}{c}{E}`

Comment: @koleygr an answer? :)

Comment: I think it is a duplicate... just answered to help the OP... If you find the duplicate, please mark the question. In other case you may provide an answer with the appropriate explanation @cmhughes (I don't really have the time for this now)

Answer (score 8):

With "clasic" `tabular` table you can solve your problem as suggested in @koleygr comment, i.e. for multicolumn cell write `\multicolumn{4}{c|}{E}`
since it overwrite right vertical line defined in column specifications.

However, you can use `tabularray` package, which for `multirow` and `multicolumn` macros use commands `SetCell[r=...]{<align>}...` and `SetCell[c=...]{<align>}...` respectively. Both doesn't interfere with table lines, which you can define in table preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skip=0.33\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \caption{Title} 
    \centering
    \label{tab:addlabel}%
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,    % table's horizontal and vertical lines
             colspec = {*{11}{c}}
             }
\SetCell[r=2]{c} A  & \SetCell[r=2]{c} B    & \SetCell[r=2]{c} C    & \SetCell[r=2]{c} D
                    & \SetCell[c=4]{c} E    
                        &   &   &           & \SetCell[r=2]{c} F    & \SetCell[r=2]{c} G 
                                            & \SetCell[r=2]{c} H                \\
\cline{5-8}
        &   &   &   & M & N & O & P         &   &   &   \\
\end{tblr}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

[image]